# Proof of non-strictly convexity of $l_1$ and $l_{\infty}$

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces, approximation-theory

Given the Banach space $l_p = \left\{f\in R^n : \|f\| \leq \infty\right\}$ for $1\leq p \leq \infty$, we define the following norms

- $\|f\|_p = \left(\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}
     |f_j|^p\,w_j\right)^{\frac{1}{p}},\quad p\geq 1,\,w_j>0,\,\forall
     j\in\mathbb N$
- $\|f\|_{\infty} = \underset{j\in\mathbb N}{\sup} |f_j|$

I want to prove that the spaces $l_1$ and $l_{\infty}$ are not strictly convex.

For $l_1$, I'm trying to find two **different** sequences $\left\{a_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\left\{b_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that

$$\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |a_n| + \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |b_n| = \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |a_n+b_n|$$

Respectively, for $l_{\infty}$, I have to find two sequences such that

$$\underset{j\in\mathbb N}{\sup} |a_j|+ \underset{j\in\mathbb N}{\sup} |b_j| = \underset{j\in\mathbb N}{\sup} |a_j+b_j|$$

are these argument correct?

If they are, then I think that I can prove it for $l_{\infty}$. One just has to take the sequences:

$$\left\{a_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}=\left\{\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $$ 
$$\left\{b_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}=\left\{\frac{1}{2n}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$$

Since then we have:

$$\underset{j\in\mathbb N}{\sup} |a_j|+ \underset{j\in\mathbb N}{\sup} |b_j| = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1 = \underset{j\in\mathbb N}{\sup} |a_j+b_j|$$

Comment: For both spaces, just take $(1,0,0,\ldots)$ and $(0,1,0,0,\ldots)$.

Comment: By the way, you need to find two non-zero elements that are *not  multiples of each other* such that your equalities hold.

Comment: It is a good idea to draw the unit balls of $\ell^1$ and $\ell^\infty$ in dimension $2$ to get a visual idea of what is going on.

Comment: I like your solution, @DavidMitra, but I don't understand your second comment, why is that necessary?

Comment: For any space, e.g., $\Vert x\Vert +\Vert 2x\Vert=\Vert x+2x\Vert$.

Comment: So, $a_n$ and $b_n$ not only have to be different but also cannot be multiples?

Comment: The vectors can't be multiples of each other (particular coordinates may be). For instance, $(1,0,\ldots)$ and $(2,0,\ldots)$ do not show that $\ell_1$ is not strictly convex; but the vectors $(1,1,0,\ldots)$ and $(2,1,0,\ldots)$ do.

Comment: Mmmh.. I'm not sure that I understand. Anyway, the vectors you proposed in the first comment don't work for the $l_{\infty}$.

Comment: Ah, sorry. For $\ell_\infty$, you could take $(1,1,0,0,\ldots)$ and $(1,0,0,\ldots)$. As for "not being multiples", if this were allowed in the definition, then no  space would be strictly convex.

Answer (score 4):

I like the geometric interpretation of "non-strictly convex": the unit sphere $\{x:\|x\|=1\}$ contains a nondegenerate line segment (line segment is degenerate if it has only one point). If one keeps this in mind and follows julien's suggestion

> It is a good idea to draw the unit balls of $\ell_1$ and $\ell_\infty$ in dimension $2$ to get a visual idea of what is going on

then the answer comes out naturally: the line segment with endpoints $e_1$ and $e_2$ (or any two vectors of the standard basis) lies on the unit sphere of $\ell_1$; also, the line segment with endpoints $e_1$ and $e_1+e_2$ lies on the unit sphere of $\ell_\infty$. This is where the examples given by David Mitra come from.

Answer (score -3):

I think

$$\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |a_n| + \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |b_n| = \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |a_n+b_n|$$

is not correct for all situations.

Consider the following 
$$\left\{a_n\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty}=\left\{-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty} $$ 
$$\left\{b_n\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty}=\left\{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$$

$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}|-\frac{1}{2^n}|+\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}|\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}| > \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}|-\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}|=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}|-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}|=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}|\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}|$$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. To prove that they are not strictly convex I just need to find a counterexample for which the equality does hold, right?

Comment: If you really check the example, you can find left hand is larger than right.

Comment: The problem is to find an example of two appropriate vectors for which the equality holds. It is not claimed that the equality holds for all pairs of vectors.

Comment: In that sense, "not strictly convex" should be explained more clear. Like in real function, $f''$ is positive more strict than non-negative?